# OpenJDK @Override missing issue

Tags: overriding, java

Is there any case that in OpenJDK 1.7.0_45, the Derived class override the base class' method, but without @Override annotation, and in runtime, the instance of derived class will invoke the base class' method?

```
class Base {
    public f() {
    }
}

class Derived {
    public f() {
    }
}
```

the Derived class's method does not call the base class's method.

BTW, the same code run well on Oracle JDK1.7.

Comment: You can compile with openjdk or oracle jdk, and run under openjdk or oracle jdk. When does this occur? Only if you both compile and run with openjdk?

Comment: @flup, I compiled both case in Oracle JDK. is this the problem?

Comment: no, that should work fine, I just wondered when exactly it occurs.

Comment: How do you determine which of the methods is called? Through calls to System.out in the method bodies?

Comment: The bytecode created by the Oracle JDK should be the same whether you added the annotation or not. So the difference should be lost even before you feed the class file to the openJDK.

Answer (score 1):

No, as you can [see in the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), @Override has [SOURCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) retention and only works as a compile time safeguard. The bytecode will not be any different. See also [How to identify override method in Java byte code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343695/how-to-identify-override-method-in-java-byte-code)

Comment: Thanks @flup.
I could not provide more context. But in my case.
If I did not add the Override annotation, the super class method will be invoked, but if i add the Override annotation, the derived class method will be invoked, this is weird.

Comment: @yilinghello that is very weird indeed, agreed!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but the override-annotation does not control which method is invoked at runtime.
So sure you can invoke the baseclass-method. Just invoke super.f().

Comment: Thanks @Seb, please see the comment I added in flup's answer.